# Map js Object to struct in V8

Tags: javascript, v8

First shot at V8, trying to get a js object cast to a c++ struct and cannot find more info on the web.

lets say I have:

```
    var brush = {
        r:255,
        g:255,
        b:255,
        a:255
    }
```

and I want to pass it to a function accepting a struct like the following:

```
struct brush{
  int r;
  int g;
  int b;
  int a;
} ;
```

How should I go about maping this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution but i must say V8 is not well documented IMHO!

```
v8::Local<v8::Object> options(args[i]->ToObject());
int r = (options->Has(v8::String::NewSymbol("red")) ? (float)options->Get(v8::String::NewSymbol("red"))->IntegerValue() : 0);
```